# How to convert htaccess to nginx

Tags: regex, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have problems to convert a htaccess file to nginx. Maybe someone can help me.

I need the following code converted:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried this but this doesnt work at all:

```
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

> ```
> location / {
>     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
> }
> ```

(I'm assuming your `.htaccess` file was in the document root.)

Your Apache `RewriteRule` directive is passing the URL-path as path-info to the `index.php` script, so your Nginx directive should be something like the following instead:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

`$uri` already contains the slash prefix. Apache also passes the query string through by default, but in Nginx you'll need to append `$is_args$args`. (`$is_args` simply contains `?` when the `$args` (query string) is non-empty.)

Comment: Generally it is working. But i have some urls ie www.example.c o m/example.php they are not working with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? Do you get an error? Is it rewriting to `index.php`? Providing `/example.php` is a physical file then the above should work OK. It would only really do something if `/example.php` didn't exist. (?)

Comment: Not working means i get a 404 error. /example.php is a physical file on the server. With Apache and htaccess it works. Really strange

Comment: What about a file like `example.txt`? I suspect there is something different with the way `.php` files are being handled on your server (I'm guessing). If the above `try_files` was not working as expected then all your CSS, JS and images (static resources) would also be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this works:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}
```

But is it safe?