# Convert Apache rewrite rules (front-controller) to Nginx

Tags: linux, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a small hand fixing rewrite rules for Nginx.

Folder structure is like this:

- `dev.example.com/public_html` << contain the site

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options -Multiviews
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^$ public_html/ [L]
      RewriteRule (.*) public_html/$1 [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

My Nginx config is a bit like this...

```
  root /data/wwwroot/domain.com/public_html;
  
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/rewrite/others.conf;
  #error_page 404 /404.html;
  #error_page 502 /502.html;
  
  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    #fastcgi_pass remote_php_ip:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
  }

  location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|flv|mp4|ico)$ {
    expires 30d;
    access_log off;
  }
  location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
    expires 7d;
    access_log off;
  }
  location ~ /(\.user\.ini|\.ht|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README\.md) {
    deny all;
  }
  location /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
```

I've some online converter but struggling to get it going.

Comment: Where are those two(?) `.htaccess` files? But the second contains the first? Those Apache directives don't make much sense unless there is another `.htaccess` file in the `/public_html` directory?

Comment: So first .htaccess is back a folder from [public_html] I believe this to prevent people trying to access folders there not ment to etc, And the second .htaccess is in [public_html]

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteRule ^$ public_html/ [L]
>   RewriteRule (.*) public_html/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

This first `.htaccess` file (above the `public_html` directory) is not required on your Nginx server since you have already configured the `root` to point directly at the `public_html` directory.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   Options -Multiviews
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteRule ^$ public_html/ [L]
>   RewriteRule (.*) public_html/$1 [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

And this `.htaccess` file (inside the `/public_html` directory) does not make sense. Specifically, the first two `RewriteRule` directives (that repeat the directives from the parent `.htaccess` file) are in error and should be deleted. If processed then this would result in a rewrite loop (500 Internal Server Error).

`Options -MultiViews` does not apply to Nginx, so this rule can be ignored.

So, the relevant directives that need "converting" are the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is a relatively standard "front-controller" pattern. However, the `url` parameter value that you are passing to the `index.php` script does not include a slash prefix. Implementing this *exactly* requires an additional step on Nginx. Ordinarily you would simply pass the URL including slash prefix and let your script handle it. (Although you don't really *need* to pass the URL-path at all, since this can be parsed from the requested URL-path - although it does allow you to "override" the requested URL-path.)

After the `root` directive, set the directory "index" document:

```
index index.php;
```

This is required when the document root is requested (the same as on Apache).

After the last `location` block, add another block for the "front-controller":

```
location ~ ^/(.+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$1$is_args$args;
}
```

The `$1` backreference refers to the captured subpattern in the `location` header - this contains the URL-path, less the slash prefix.

The additional `$is_args$args` is necessary to append any additional query string that might be present on the initial request. (This is equivalent to the `QSA` mod_rewrite flag on Apache.)

If, however, you are OK with including the slash prefix on the URL-path to your script in the `url` parameter then the above can be "simplified" to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

But note that this version is not exactly the same as the equivalent Apache/`.htaccess` directives.

---

Alternative, [passing the URL-path as PATH_INFO after `index.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66937169/369434).

---

> Folder structure is like this:
>
> - `dev.example.com/public_html` << contain the site

Note that with your Nginx config, the `public_html` directive *is* the document root, so `dev.example.com/` refers directly to this directory.

Comment: This did allow me to load site and login, but afterwards site is constanstly refreshing etc and shoutbox is unusable

Comment: @user19097640 That sounds like a client-side/JavaScript issue not necessarily related to the directives in the server config? What do you see in the network traffic? Any 404s? Bear in mind that it looks like the document root directory might be set differently on Nginx. On Nginx it is pointing directly at the `public_html` directory (as it should be), whereas on Apache it looks like it was perhaps pointing to the directory above `public_html` and mod_rewrite was then being used to rewrite requests to the subdirectory (arguably a "workaround").

Comment: That correct, I'll have look and report back etc

Comment: I can't see any errors, but the site is constanstly refreshing every second 1 etc